# Using ffmpeg to analyze a Unicast stream from Wirecast

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, unicast

I am using Wirecast to send out a unicast stream.  It looks like this `udp://@:5434`.  I am trying to use ffmpeg to analyze this stream for blackdetect and freezedetect.

What I have tried so far is `ffmpeg -i udp://@:5434 -filter:v blackdetect=d=9 -filter:a silencedetect=d=9 -t 10 -f null /dev/null`, however this has given the error: `Invalid data when processing the input`

I can decode the unicast in VLC by opening the .sdp file.

Any help to understanding this would be great.  Thank you!

[image: Screen shot of wirecast unicast settings]

Comment: What's the format and codec of the stream?

Comment: Hi Gyan, Thank you for answering.  The format is `RTP H.264 720p 16:9 (1280x720)` 2563 k bitrate.  I will include a screenshot.  Thank you.

Comment: Specify the input in `rtp://...` form.

Comment: Thank you, Gyan, so it would be something like `ffmpeg -i rtp://@:5434 -filter:v blackdetect=d=9 -filter:a silencedetect=d=9 -t 10 -f null /dev/null` ?  Thank you!  I will give it a shot.

Comment: I ran this command above and got the error `Unable to receive RTP payload type 97 without an SDP file describing it`.  The actual command I ran was `ffmpeg -i rtp://192.168.0.184:5434 -filter:v blackdetect=d=9 -filter:a silencedetect=d=9 -t 10 -f null /dev/null`

Comment: Ok, then `ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,crypto,rtp,tcp,udp -i myfile.sdp ...`

Comment: Thank you.  This worked.  I really appreciate your time.